# Website to record a video and host it

Tags: web-apps, video, webcam

Does anyone know an API to record a video with webcam and host it on a user’s profile?

I would like to build a website where the user will create a profile and will be able to record a video with his webcam and upload it to his profile.

Comment: Do you want a library that you can host on your own website? Is a third-party service OK? In that case, should the video be private, or can it be viewable publicly on the third party website as well?

Answer (score 1):

Youtube allows you do this:

https://www.youtube.com/my_webcam

Press on "Start recording" on that page.
The produced video will be available from your profile page.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the OP looks for a library to be used on his own site, rather then an offsite resource.